# Setting Variables as Type Template

Tags: c++, templates, game-engine

So I'm working on a text-based RPG and I've run into an issue. I am working on the character's ability to equip a weapon from their inventory. I have type `Weapon`, which is a child class of type `Item`; I also have various other class types that can be stored inside the player's inventory. What I am working on right now, is making sure that the item the player wants to equip is of type `Weapon`; in this, I am working with templates (which I am fairly new to using), so that I have some sort of universal type for testing. The code is as follows:

```
template <class T>
void MyCharacter::equipWeapon(){
    Weapon testForEquipping;                
    T chosenWeapon;                         
    chosenWeapon = myInventory.chooseItem();
    if(typeid(chosenWeapon).name() == typeid(testForEquipping).name()){
        //Haven't added what will happen with this part yet.
    }

    Weapon tempWeapon1 = equippedWeapon;
    Weapon tempWeapon2 = chosenWeapon;

    equippedWeapon = tempWeapon2;
    chosenWeapon = tempWeapon1;
}
```

As you can see, I am wanting to set `chosenWeapon` equal to the chosen item in the player's inventory; (this part works). However, the issue lies within this error that I get when I try to run the function in the program `error: no matching function for call to 'MyCharacter::equipWeapon()'`. Despite my research into the problem, I don't understand what I am doing wrong! Any help or new suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be done at runtime, so templates is not the right tool to use. Instead you should use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
void MyCharacter::equipWeapon() {
    Item item = myInventory.chooseItem();
    if (Weapon* weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(&item)) {
        // Equip the weapon
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory method design pattern:

"In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created. This is done by creating objects by calling a factory method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern